# How to give uniform thicknes to edges of an object using materials(nodes)?

Tags: materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, mathematics, texture-coordinates

Here I want to create a thick border around my object using materials (Nodes).
Here is my model and material.
[image]
[image: Nodes I have used to create above material]
But, when we see closely, there is a variation in thickness of side borders.
The side borders are slightly thinner on top and thicker on bottom. 
What is the best possible way of getting uniform thick border on sides of this kind of objects?

*Note: What I meant uniform is, The border should have constant thickness from top to bottom.*

Comment: Are you using cycles or EEVEE? All material/ shading  questions should be tagged with the render engine being used to avoid confusion.

Comment: EEVEE render engine